# How to find the Missing ID using find Query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a query in MongoDB like:

```
db.getCollection('customerOrder').find({
  "orderDocument.accountInfo.ban": { 
    $in: ["330650872","330651099","330651125","330651561","330681521"]
  }
})
```

and i am passing 5 ban and only 3 ban is found and 2 ban not found.
i want to know the missing ban in console. I am Using Robo3t editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find your matched results(i.e. 3 records), group them together as a list. Then use [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to compare your full list to find the 2 missing ones.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vM2fB8Kifgr)